Existence of a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ which has the internal standard model of arithmetic coincide with the real standard model of arithmetic
$\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ can prove that there is a model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ which has the natural numbers structure
$\mathbb{N}^M$ as the standard model of arithmetic inside $M$ but $\mathbb{N}^M \ncong \mathbb{N}$ holds outside, where $\mathbb{N}$ means the real standard model of arithmetic in the meta-theory $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$.
Then, can we take a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ which has the internal standard model of arithmetic coincide with the external standard model of arithmetic in this setting ?
That is, does the following statement hold ?
$\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \vdash$  "there is a model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ which has $\mathbb{N}^M$ inside $M$ and $\mathbb{N}^M \cong \mathbb{N}$ outside"
Here, we assume $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is consistent in a meta-meta-position, or the statement becomes trivial and "$\cong(\ncong)$" means the isomorphic(non-isomorphic) relation as arithmetic structure, so we don't care about membership "$\in$" relational structure (we omit such as the difference between von Neumann construction and Zermelo construction).
And what about unique (up to isomorphism) infinite structures other than $\mathbb{N}$ ?
I would appreciate any help !

Hi, welcome to Math SE. The usual symbol is $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (\mathsf{ZFC}).

Thank you for the comment ! I edited.

The answer is negative. Suppose that $M$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$ and $\Bbb N^M=\Bbb N$ (after all, if they are isomorphic, we might as well put the actual $\Bbb N$ in there).
We can check that every arithmetic statement (that is, a first-order statement in the language of arithmetic) will now be true in $\Bbb N^M$ if and only if it will be true in $\Bbb N$. In particular, the statement $\operatorname{Con}({\sf ZFC})$, which is a $\Pi_1$ statement (so not even a complicated one). The key point here is that when we formalise what $\sf ZFC$ means, since there are only standard integers, there is no way to get any non-standard axioms or non-standard proofs (i.e. things that go beyond the standard integers in length or whatnot). But even more, the statement $\operatorname{Con}({\sf ZFC}+\operatorname{Con}({\sf ZFC}))$ is true in $\Bbb N$, since we have a model of this theory, and therefore would be true in $M$.
By Gödel's incompleteness theorem, therefore, there must be models in which $\Bbb N$ is non-standard. Note that this can lift to iterated-consistency statements through all the arithmetic ordinals for the same reason. So, to say that a model of $\sf ZFC$ has a standard [copy of] $\Bbb N$ requires a significantly stronger assumption than just the consistency of $\sf ZFC$.
Even more than that, if $M$ is a transitive model (i.e., the set $M$ satisfies $x\in M\to x\subseteq M$ and the $\in$ relation is the real one inherited from the universe), then $M$ has a standard copy of $\Bbb N$, but we can show that this statement is even stronger than just having a standard copy of the integers.
(Just to help you read about it elsewhere, if $M$ has a standard copy of the integers we say that it is an $\omega$-model.)

Thank you for the answer and clarifying the point !  I should have realized that the arithmetical soundness is stronger than just the consistency for theories to which Gödel's incompleteness theorem is applicable.  But I didn't know having a transitive model is stronger than having a $\omega$-model for $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and the word "$\omega$-model". Thank you for supporting my understanding !

@Pointwise It's worth noting that this phenomenon generalizes. E.g. there's a notion of "$\beta$-model" which is even stronger than "$\omega$-model," and ZFC + "ZFC has an $\omega$-model" does not prove "ZFC has a $\beta$-model." There's a whole hierarchy of "correctness notions" and general Godelian phenomena mean that ZFC + "ZFC has a somewhat-correct model" never implies "ZFC has a very-correct model" (barring inconsistency of course). Here Con(ZFC) is just "ZFC has a not-necessarily-at-all-correct model," i.e. corresponds to the lowest level of the "correctness hierarchy."

I probably misunderstand something, but I think your answer shows that not all models are $\omega$-models, but the question was if there necessary is an $\omega$-model.

@mihaild: If it there was always one, we could have proved it. And the point is that we can't.

@AsafKaragila thanks, I understand the line of reasoning now. But why is $\operatorname{Con}({\sf ZFC}+\operatorname{Con}({\sf ZFC}))$ true in $\mathbb N$, where $\mathbb N$ are natural numbers in meta-model (and not in meta-meta-model)?

@mihaild How about this explanation ? From now we are working in $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$. If $M$ is a $\omega$-model, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent $ \Leftrightarrow M \vDash \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ holds. Since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, we have $M \vDash \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ and also $M \vDash \mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$.

Then we can prove $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is consistent by the soundness theorem of first-order logic. That is, we proved the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ in $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$! But from now we are in a meta-meta-position, this is impossible if $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is consistent by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.

If we use the assumption that $M$ is a $\omega$-model again when we proved the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$,
then we get $M \vDash \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}))$ by the statement $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is consistent $ \Leftrightarrow M \vDash \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}))$ within $\mathsf{ZFC} + \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ and we can repeat this process like Asaf explains.

@Pointwise: Exactly!
